# remotely view error asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

But I need to be able to see where the problem is. Could anyone suggest any method I can see what is the problem logging or something. I think that web.config may be wrong or something. I dont have access to iis so I need other solution. Thanks for help

Comment: What do you have access to?  do you have access to the server running the website? Do you have access to the web.config file?

Comment: I have access to the folder in which app is. I have access to web.Config, yes

Answer (score 2):

Check your [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) element in web.config.  It's likely set to 'RemoteOnly' or 'On'--setting it to 'Off' will allow you to view the error page.  As a longer term strategy you may want to consider a logging mechanism, like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Comment: @gruber: And you're still seeing the issue?  Is there another web.config at a lower directory level which might be overriding it?

Answer (score 1):

Update the `web.config` [`customErrors` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) and set the `mode` attribute to `off`.

This will allow you to see the yellow screen of death.

Don't forget to set it back when finished.

A long term solution is to add logging to your application so you can have a log of issues at hand.

Comment: already done, but I cant see the error. I only can see that there is server error, thats all

Comment: @gruber - start cleaning up the webconfig. Open it in visual studio and fix any errors.

Comment: on my local machine it worsk correctly, on production doesnt so it isnt parsing problem

Comment: @gruber - is IIS using the right .NET version? Is it setup to use .NET at all?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can get access to the server to run the application from there?

If you can get to the app.config / web.config file you'll be able to change the error settings to allow errors to be viewed remotely, the full error screen you get in your browser should tell you what changes need to be made.

Comment: No, you change the application's config file, you don't need IIS, but you do need access to the server (or someone who can get you a copy of the file you need so you can update it and have it re-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it sound like turning off the custome error will give you more information See [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) page for more information on the custom error setting in web.config