# Site functions locally, "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" on server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.Net Website (not a web app, fwiw) that builds and works just fine locally through IIS on my dev laptop.

However, when I publish it to our QA box and try to view while I'm remoting into that server, I get a message from IE saying "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Firefox just spits back a quick "Connection Timed Out"

There is absolutely nothing in the event log nor the IIS log about this. I'm unsure where I can look for more info.

I'm fairly confident it is an ASP.Net issue. I can install a sample site from our vendor, Ektron, into IIS and it will run. If I overwrite the sample's web.config with my own, it continues to run. If I then blow away the entire sample site and copy over my site from my local, I'll get the message about how "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

I've tried to keep the environments as close together as I can. Both boxes are running IIS 7.5 under an integrated app pool for .Net 4.0. I browse via `localhost` on dev and via an IP on the server.

I am not terribly familiar with the Website template, so I might be missing something obvious (I hope!).  I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance into how I can get more info on what the heck is going on so I can resolve this issue.

UPDATE

I think I'm getting closer. By using Fiddler (thanks for the suggestion, Amy!) I notice that it redirects the request to SSL. SSL requires a different license from our vendor, so that might be it. I'm still trying to understand why that redirect is taking place, but at least I have something now to look at.

Comment: Try to inspect the request/response using fiddler. Looks like the request never reach the server. Could be an proxy/routing/firewall issue given that you can't see anything in IIS logs.

Comment: I'm getting these issues while I'm remoting into the server, shouldn't be a network issue. And the sample site functions from remote.

Comment: Turn on remote viewing of errors on the server.  Also, add logging to your ASP.Net application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226127/remotely-view-error-asp-net

Comment: Fiddler tells you more than just network issues.  It's worth the time to inspect what it tells you.  I suspect you're getting a 500 error back from the server.  The Fiddler response inspector may provide more information.

Comment: @Amy CustomErrors was already configured properly, but your Fiddler suggestion may have provided some valuable insight.

Comment: The redirect may be coming from IIS. Is the website set to only accept SSL connections? Failing that is there anything in your .Net code that checks for the presence of SSL and redirects if does not find it? Ektron will only enforce SSL when you log into the CMS itself, i.e. the Workarea.

Comment: Appreciate all the effort, guys. Turns out buried in the code there was a line that checked the URL for `localhost`, and if it wasn't there, redirected over SSL. Amy's Fiddler suggestion switched the lightbulb on for me, I'll remember to keep it in my toolkit at all times!

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into the SSL settings in the web.config / IIS - settings for Mime Types and also into Ektron's MIME Types in the MimeType.config file.   I found that some .aspx pages like (ekajaxtransform.aspx) weren't functioning correctly because of firewall/proxy issues/restrictions.

Hope it helps. :)